# Sendgrid Python library and templates

Tags: python, sendgrid

I am trying to use templates which I have created on Sendgrid. What I want to do is, use the template that I have created on Sendgrid to send an email (with substituting the substitution tags).

Here is what I tried -

```
import sendgrid
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('<username>', '<password>')
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('<to-email-address>')
message.set_subject('My Test Email')
message.add_substitution('customer_link', 'http://my-domain.com/customer-id')
message.add_filter('templates', 'enable', '1')
message.add_filter('templates', 'template_id', '<alphanumeric-template-id>')
message.add_from('<from-email-address>')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

However, this gives me an error that `'{"errors":["Missing email body"],"message":"error"}'`. I tried adding the following lines but still the same error -

```
message.set_html('')
message.set_text('')
```

So, the exact code I am using after using `set_html` is -

```
import sendgrid
sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('<username>', '<password>')
message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('<to-email-address>')
message.set_subject('My Test Email')
message.add_substitution('customer_link', 'http://my-domain.com/customer-id')
message.add_filter('templates', 'enable', '1')
message.add_filter('templates', 'template_id', '<alphanumeric-template-id>')
message.add_from('<from-email-address>')
message.set_html('')
message.set_text('')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

What am I missing here? The python documentation for the library doesn't seem to contain anything.

Edit - One of the workaround that I found is derived from the answer below. I do set `message.set_html(' ')` and `message.set_text(' ')`, that is basically, give a whitespace string. This is weird, though, but works for this case.

Comment: so what is the exact code you are using after adding the `set_html` and `_text` parts?

Comment: @fedorqui added the exact code. The exact code just adds the `set_html` and `set_text`.

Comment: Note that newer versions of the python sendgrid library now use `sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/python.html) it is indeed poor, since it just mentions an example. However, it provides you a link to its Github [sendgrid-python](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) repository in which you can find broader examples and the code itself (sometimes it is faster to look at this!).

Find here a full example listed in the [Github page](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python#example):

```
import sendgrid

sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('YOUR_SENDGRID_USERNAME', 'YOUR_SENDGRID_PASSWORD')

message = sendgrid.Mail()
message.add_to('John Doe <john@email.com>')
message.set_subject('Example')
message.set_html('Body')
message.set_text('Body')
message.set_from('Doe John <doe@email.com>')
status, msg = sg.send(message)

#or

message = sendgrid.Mail(to='john@email.com', subject='Example', html='Body', text='Body', from_email='doe@email.com')
status, msg = sg.send(message)
```

---

However, in this case you are using a template and in Sendgrid's blog they mention:

> **[Template Engine Demo – Q&A](https://sendgrid.com/blog/template-engine-demo-qa/)**
>
> Do I have to use the body and subject substitution tags in my
>   template? What If I don’t want to pass any substitution variables in
>   my email?
>
> No. You can pass a blank value through with your API call and not
>   specify any variables.

although apparently it is not like this and you need to append some kind of html and text in your `message` instance.

So the workaround here is what you discovered: to set the html and text to a non-empty string:

```
message.set_html(' ')
message.set_text(' ')
```

Comment: This is not what I am trying to do. I am trying to use a template. Please take a closer look at the question.

Comment: The error you are getting is related to not adding the email body *because your code is not adding it*. Edit your question and show it. By the way, downvoting people trying to help your unclear question is not likely to give you a lot of success here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am adding the body like `message.set_html('')` and `message.set_text('')` as I have mentioned in the question. If I do pass some arbitrary string in `set_html` and `set_text` it is appended to the top of the template which is not what I want. Also, I'm wondering why is it required to set the body at all as all I want is to use a template which already has all the content. Any ideas?

Comment: @Siddharth So you have a template and you want to fill it by using the `add_substitution()` and `add_filter()`. However, this is going to interact on the data you are providing and now you are not giving any. Probably you need to say `message.set_html(your_template)`?

Comment: I don't think I am explaining correctly. I have defined the template on Sendgrid (it is not something my code defines). And I want to use substitution on the template which I have defined on Sendgrid. I have made an edit to the question with a workaround but I don't fully understand. I don't think I can do `message.set_html(your_template)` as there is no `your_template`. All I have is the `template-id` from Sendgrid. Not sure, if this makes sense.

Comment: @Siddharth ok now I understand. I have worked with Sendgrid, but never with these templates. It looks like their behaviour is confusing, because even their blog mention you don't need to add such values. See my update with a reference.

Comment: Yep, it works if I set the `html` and `text` to a non-empty string. Think will have to live with it. Could you edit your answer with this detail so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: @Siddharth so you solved it yourself : ) Updated showing this. Glad that this was solved.

Comment: @Siddharth Were you able to use the substitution in SG templates, created on their dashboard? I am facing issues with the same. Keys replaced by blank values.

Comment: @mynk I ended up using Mailgun instead of Sendgrid as it was much easier to work with Mailgun. I don't remember much about this issue anymore. Sorry, could not be of more help.